# How can I add items to the beginning of my ListView without scrolling?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to add items to the beginning of my ListView when the user scrolls up.  I've tried adding items to the start of the list, but as expected, the new items push the old items down the list.

I kind of want infinite scroll, but in both directions, both up and down.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: There is probably a widget for that! try the `SliverList` widget. it is way more powerful than a simple `ListView` and might be the thing you're looking for.

Comment: Okay, checking SliverList now.  I still can't see a way to do this...

Comment: Did you figure this out?